# How can I monitor water usage for just my portion of a shared property?

Tags: water, meter

I live at a property of 4 bungalows. We are all on 1 water meter. We have all been told by the property owner that our monthly charge for water is going up because of higher use. My neighbors and I believe it to be the fault of one bungalow's occupant. Is there something on the market that we can attach to the main coming into our homes that will monitor how much we are using?

Comment: Yes. Google water meters, you can buy your own. It would only be effective if all 4 bungalows had them tho.  They are not too pricey either.

Comment: Why yes - it's called a water meter. Or in this case, 3 water meters. You can subtract your three from the single meter to determine the use of the "presumed problem" bungalow.

Comment: Maybe I'm not asking clealy, I don't want to put in a full meter for the utilities to read, I'm looking for something smaller that we can read and monitor ourselves

Comment: Do you know if that is very expensive?

Comment: If you got cheap meters, and they showed that the fourth bungalow was apparently consuming all the water, the fourth's owner could quite reasonably claim that the cheap meters were inaccurate and wrong.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I wouldn't use 3 and subtract, I'd use 4 as a sanity check (I.e all 4 should add up to close to what the utility billed) .. Cherie1313 the utility wouldn't read them, they will only read their main meter, but all 4 sub-meters.  This is known as sub-metering.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to be very careful about installing and changing things on the property since you are not the property owner. If it comes down to needing to have individual water meters at each unit the best thing would be to work out an agreement with the owner to switch over to actual usage billing.

Part of the negotiation process could be agreement that the various tenants will chip for part of the cost of the meters.